# Detect ICC vs GCC at compile time

Tags: c++, c, gcc, icc, predefined-macro

How to detect at compile time if I'm using gcc or icc?

(I was quite puzzled to find out that icc defines `__GNUC__` -- and even `__GNUC_MINOR__` and `__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__` ! why?)

Comment: Clang also defines these, they are for compatibility purposes: you can just replace the `gcc` command with `icc`, with the exact same options, without anything breaking (or that's the idea).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We use

```
#ifdef __INTEL_COMPILER
```

to split `icc` off, assuming `gcc` as a default.

Answer (score 9):

I believe you could check for `__INTEL_COMPILER` according to [this](http://predef.sourceforge.net/precomp.html#sec23).

Comment: This is more transparent https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/boost/config/compiler/intel.hpp

Answer (score 1):

The reason ICC defines `__GNUC__` etc. is because of code like yours that is inspecting compiler-specific macros and expects to see them...

Comment: You make it sound like it is a) his fault, b) not a good thing to do without giving any explanation.

Comment: Another way to put this is that ICC implements the GNU dialect of C (and C++), and that's what the presence of `__GNUC__` indicates.  It doesn't mean that the compiler is the GNU implementation of the GNU C language.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, compilers have defined a symbol of their own as well as their version as preprocessor symbols so that the code could be adapted (generally to work around bugs or specificities).

CLang has introduced a mechanism I had not seen so far, under the form of the `__has_feature` query. It does not replace the "work around bugs" practices (which is why CLang still exposes specific symbols) but allows a more natural style for querying the compiler capacities. I don't know if other compilers plan on defining such a facility.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the processor output the defined macros in the preprocessor output and look for a macro that suits you. You can generated the preprocessor output like this:

```
icc  -dM -E -o foo.P foo.c
```

Then look at `foo.P` (since it is a text file). In my case, I found `icc` defined an `__ICC` macro with the version of the compiler. It didn't define any `__INTEL_COMPILER` though.